# Creating histogram at each pixel location considering the window around it in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, histogram

I have to create local histograms at each pixel considering some neighboring window of the pixel.

```
numpy.histogram(image,bins=256)
```

creates the histogram of the whole image. I could give it a specific part of the image but I don't want to use the loops.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what kind of output you are expecting? The output of every call to `histogram` is a vector of counts (and another of bin locations), so you need to decide how you want that information stored for every call in your x,y looping.

Comment: The output would be a 2d array of histograms where the histogram index is the corresponding (x,y) pixel in the image. for histogram it will contain the bins specified by the user.

Answer (score 0):

This code should get you the histogram of the part of the image in the rectangle whose upper left corner is `(x1, y1)` and lower right corner is `(x2, y2)`:

```
numpy.histogram(image[x1:x2, y1:y2], bins=256)
```

If you want to do this for each pixel in an image, you are going to have to use loops.

Comment: thanks, I was looking for a pythonic way, actually I am sure there must be a way to do it!

Comment: If you define a function that creates the local histogram at a pixel, you might be able to use `map` to call that function for each pixel in image.  That at least pushes the loop to where you can't see it, although you'll end up with an array of histograms.

Comment: You might also consider using the `numpy.ndimage` `generic_filter`, http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Ndimage

Comment: @mutzmatron, I don't exactly know how to do it generic_filter. It would be nice if you could please post a sample code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Shan - Given the desired output, `generic_filter` won't work (it gives an output that is the same size as the input). I would imagine map would be the way to go.

Comment: Does image[x1:x2, y1:y2] create a copy of the image? If it does, then this will be inefficient.

Comment: If image is an `ndarray` then I think it will not create a copy -- numpy generally doesn't create copies of arrays unless you explicitly tell it to.